# Transition matrix and probability in the long term

Tags: matrices, transition-matrix

I finish to do an exercise but I am not quite sure how to resolve the last question. Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Exercise: 
Sylvie is in good health (state 1) or she is sick (state 2). In 98% of cases, when she is in good health on a given day, she will still be healthy the next day. In addition, in 40% of cases, when she is sick on a given day, she will regain her health the next day. Let T be the transition matrix, where t(ij) represents the probability that Sylvie will move from state j to state i.

(a)If Sylvie is sick today, use matrix multiplication to determine the probability that it will still be in two days.
(b)In the long term, what percentage of days will Sylvie be healthy?

**What I've done**:
The transition matrix:$
$
    \begin{matrix}
0.98 & 0.4 \\
0.02 & 0.6  \\
\end{matrix}

Let P(0) be the vector of the initial state :$
$
    \begin{matrix}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{matrix}

*Let's calculate P(2).*

P(2) = T.T.P(0) which make:$
$
    \begin{matrix}
0.632\\
0.368 \\
\end{matrix}

So there is a probability of 36.8% that Sylvie will still be sick in two days.

Comment: To find the probability over the long term, you need to find the limit of $P(n)$ when $n$ goes to infinity. If we assume this limit exists (we know it does from general theorem on Markov chains), let's denote it $P$, we can show it satisfies the equation $P = T P$. So you can compute it be solving the resulting linear system.

Comment: Thank you. But I have one last question @JoelCohen, how do we choose the vector of the initial state? Is it arbitrary or there is a convention?

Comment: The initial state is irrelevant to the long run probabilities, but for example in part (a) it was given. Otherwise some assumption is generally made.

Comment: Okay so if I understand well, I could have used [0 1] in (a) and you could have used  [1 0] ? Am I right? @Math1000

Comment: In part (a) it is given that Sylvie is sick to begin with, so the initial distribution would be $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: thank you for your help @Math1000 :).